# Symfony 5 Convert string to datetime

Tags: symfony, datetime

In Symfony 5 I have a form where users enter into text fields and also a date. This is then redirected into a display controller that displays matching rows from the database. The date needed to be converted into a string for the redirect to work.

```
        $firstName = $findPt->getFirstName();
        $surname = $findPt->getSurname();
        $username = $findPt->getUsername();
        $dob = $findPt->getDateOfBirth();
        $dobStringValue = $dob->format('Y-m-d');
        
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_displayClients', ['firstName' => $firstName,
                                        'surname' => $surname, 
                                        'username' => $username,
                                        'dob' => $dobStringValue]);
```

However in the display controller I then need to convert it back into a datetime to use it but that doesn't seem possible. I've tried various options, such as $dobDateTime= new DateTime($dateStr);

Please let me know if this question isn't clear or you need more information.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reconvert it using [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$dobStringValue = $dob->format('Y-m-d');
$dobReconverted = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $dobStringValue);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've been trying alternatives like this but using Symfony it gives the error: Attempted to load class "DateTime" from namespace "App\Controller".
Did you forget a "use" statement for "Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\DateTime"?

Comment: you might have to add a \ infront of DateTime if you are not injecting DateTime

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Agnohendrix, that was helpful. I didn't need to format as it was already a string but used $dobReconverted =  \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $dobStringValue);
The \ seemed to have been what made it work, maybe this is something to do with using Symfony.

Answer (score 0):

It works with "\Datetime" and not with "Datetime" because "Datetime" needs to be defined with a "use Datetime" to work; that's why the error "Did you forget a use statement for..." came out.